# Copy text from input fields and paste into other input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Copy button works perfect copy text from first input field and click on paste button paste in it

```
<input type="text" id="txt1">Some text</input> 
<input type="button" value="copy" >

<input type="text" id="txt2">Some text 2</input> 
<input type="button" value="copy2" >

<input type="text"></input>
<input type="button" value="paste text" >
```

Comment: didn't get your question?? please explain briefly??

Comment: text copy from input field which is "some text"  than click on paste text button paste the text into input fields

Comment: set the global variable. when click copy button store the value in global variable. when user click paste button append the value with global variable.

Comment: thanks but i want to do this using jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution. Add handler to the `copy` buttons and on each click get the previous `input` field's value and store in a variable. Then in the `paste` click set the text into the value of the `paste` button.

If you have this structure of html, in this way it will be easy to do (with `prev()`).

```js
var text = '';

$('.copy').on('click', function(){
  text = $(this).prev().val();
});

$('#paste').on('click', function(){
  $(this).prev().val(text);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="Some Text 1"/>
<input type="button" class="copy" value="copy" >

<input type="text" id="txt2"  value="Some Text 2"/>
<input type="button" class="copy" value="copy2" >

<input type="text"/>
<input id="paste" type="button" value="paste text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

since you said it's working perfectly then i understand your question is which language is used there, it's neither javascript or jquery, pure html is used only for that

Answer (score 0):

```
var copy_text= '';

$('.copy_button').on('click', function(){
  copy_text = $(this).prev().val();
});

$('.paste_button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).prev().val(copy_text);
});
```